# Trying to better understand the models I've created with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was pointed toward ggplot2 as an effective tool for data visualization and it's been tremendously helpful, but I'm trying to fully understand exactly what I've done and I'm having a bit of trouble finding the proper resources to tell me.

```
library(ggplot2)

bone <- read.csv('/Users/kylehammerberg/Desktop/ML Extra Credit/spnbmd.csv')

### Generate scatter plot of data
ggplot(bone) + aes(age, spnbmd, color=sex)  + geom_point()


### Fit splines to both male and female bone density data 
### geom_point to create scatter plot 
### geom_smooth to fit splines 
ggplot(bone) + aes(age, spnbmd, color=sex)  + geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(formula = y~splines::bs(x, knots=c(10,15,20)), method="lm")

### Fit splines to bone density by race
ggplot(bone) + aes(age, spnbmd, color=ethnic)  + geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(formula = y~splines::bs(x, knots=c(10,15,20)), method="lm")
```

I don't know exactly what the bs() part of the code is doing and I want to better understand the shaded regions around the generated splines. Are they some sort of confidence interval?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are.

The help function in R is, well, helpful.

```r
help(geom_smooth)
help( "bs::splines" )
```

Although not straightforward stated what the shaded region is, the `geom_smooth` manual page will tell you this on the `se` argument:

```
      se: Display confidence interval around smooth? (‘TRUE’ by
          default, see ‘level’ to control.)
```

Also for this kind of illustration it's pretty much a given that the shaded region is in fact some sort of uncertainty representation.

The manual page for `bs::splines` will tell you that it creates a B-spline. To say what that is and isn't is beyond the scope of this site. You will have better luck at stats.stackexchange.com, and for that matter wikipedia:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=B-spline
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

But suffice to say, they construct those solid lines that you see that are in a way a sort of running average of the data behind it. In your case done separate for each group as per the color you specify.